# How to configure Apahce with websocket through python daphne DJango on EC2 server

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, python, django, websocket

Below is my virtual host for running python

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/VITSBACKEND
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:8000%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
    ProxyPass /ws/  ws://127.0.0.1:8000
   

    Alias /media/ /var/www/backend/web/
    <Directory /var/www/backend/web>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/backend/main>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess main python-path=/var/www/backend python-home=/var/www/backend/env
    WSGIProcessGroup main
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/backend/main/wsgi.py
```

How to run daphne channels here, I need to access it via webserver and need it to run via apache only.

Can anyone answer here.